# R Eigenvector Centrality with Weight

Tags: r, graph, igraph, eigenvector, weighting

I'm woking with R and the eigenvector centrality algorithm from the igraph library. We have the following sql table :

```
person1 / person2 / score

A / B / 0.568

A / C / 1.233

B / A / 0.798

B / C / 0.493

C / A / 1.367

C / B / 1.276
```

The values are a score for the relationship between the two person.

Two question : 
- How can I create a matrix in R from the table above with the score as a weight ?
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zetZl.png)

```
Person   A       B     C 
A        -     0.568  1.233
B      0.798     -    0.493
C     1.367    1.276   -
```

- How can we take into a consideration the weight of the relationship to apply eigenvector centrality algorithm in R?

Answer (score 2):

To apply the edge-weights in the calculation of eigenvector centrality, simply reference the weights with the `weights` option of `eigen_centrality`:

```
rm(list=ls())

library(igraph)

# Some sample data, source: http://www.shizukalab.com/toolkits/sna/weighted-edgelists
el <- structure(list(V1 = c(23732L, 23732L, 23778L, 23778L, 23871L, 
23871L, 23871L, 58009L, 58098L, 58256L), V2 = c(23871L, 58098L, 
23732L, 23824L, 23778L, 58009L, 58098L, 58098L, 23778L, 58098L
), weight = c(1L, 10L, 8L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "weight"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))

g <- graph.data.frame(el)

# Only showing the centrality scores, hence the $vector
eigen_centrality(g, directed=TRUE, weights=E(g)$weight)$vector

#     23732      23778      23871      58009      58098      58256      23824 
# 0.53685043 0.39782138 0.09055835 0.01527579 1.00000000 0.00000000 0.06710630
```

To get the adjacency matrix of weights:

```
get.adjacency(g, attr='weight')
```

Comment: Can you post your output? The call `E(g)` returns `NULL` using the example.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick and dirty way by creating a new matrix, naming the rows and columns by person 1 and 2, then assigning the values to the right spot. We use two R tips that aren't talked about enough to new users.

1) You can extract elements of an object by their name.

2) You can use a two-column matrix for subsetting.

```
p1 <- sort(unique(df$person1))
p2 <- sort(unique(df$person2))
mat <- matrix(0, length(p1), length(p2))
rownames(mat) <- p1
colnames(mat) <- p2
mat[as.matrix(df[1:2])] <- df$score
mat
#        A     B     C 
# A  0.000 0.568 1.233
# B  0.798 0.000 0.493
# C  1.367 1.276 0.000
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. we have 20 unique data person1 and this will give ZERO to all the scores in the matrix witch is not true because we are having several scores.

There is an example of the data in the table :

person1           person2        score

16182470        79389918      3.1

72765516         61389465     3.2


I will have a matrix after the code with 

         61389465 79389918


16182470        0        0


72765516        0        0

How can I correct that ?

Comment: Adding code to the comments doesn't help. Please make edits in your question.

Comment: Hi Pierre, to resume, The code is able to extract the unique value of persone1 and person2 but gives 0 for all the score value in the matrix.. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: I have shown you that it works for your example.

Comment: Please post data showing the problematic behavior. Post it to your question.